# jQuery Tools - How do you use history plugin as a standalone?

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools

In the jQuery Tools demos and documentation, the history plugin is usually seen with tabs.

I looked at the documentation and it seems that there is no example for standalone use.

Any tips on how to use it?

Comment: Why would you need a history plugin as a standalone? The main reason you'll find the use of a history plugin in combination with tabs, is because those are all on a single page (the build-in history navigator of your browser doesn't see that as browsing to an actual other page).

Comment: @MarcoK It is because I want to use it without tabs. I am not saying that I want this to be a separate js, just using it in another context other than tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could dive into the [**jQuery hashchange**](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-hashchange) plugin; it's a history plugin that works when the part after the hash (`#`) changes. This way, you can fully customize it to your needs (without using tabs).